# Button command execution issue with touch | WPF | MVVM | Windows 10

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, windows-10, touch

I am using a simple button in a WPF application running on Windows 10 using MVVM pattern to execute action on click with command binding using touch monitor. What actually happen is sometimes the first time command action is not executing on touch and it is working correctly after second touch onward.

I have verified that the TouchDown and TouchUp event is working correctly all the time (first and onward).

With mouse everything is working well.

The button is present in a Dialog box, I was wondering if it could be associated with any kind of focus management but can't find out ? Please help!

Best regards,
HPS.

Comment: Often things like this are becuase the DataContext has been changed. Check carefully that you don't reassign the DataContext, but just change the underlying state

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the problem was RealTimeStylus for WPF Applications that should be disabled on Windows 7.

Please check here for details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/disable-the-realtimestylus-for-wpf-applications?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8.